# Forefront TMG client

Tags: tmg

Currently we have Sonicwall as our network gateway and I'm planning to use Forefront TMG for our web filtering purpose without changing Sonicwall as our primary GW.

Is there a Forefront TMG client app which I can just install on our domain client computers for filtering to work via TMG?

Comment: I'd like to steer away from TMG but it's what we have for now. Is there a TMG client application which can be installed on machines and does the web filter via the TMG?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid TMG, as to my knowledge, it is discontinued. Personally, i'd also steer clear of web filter clients, unless you have a real need to run one - perhaps off-site filtering. Generally they're a bit more hassle than they are worth. Domain clients should happily take a proxy, and authenticate against it with Kerberos.

There are numerous excellent good value alternatives to TMG from companies like Bluecoat, Smoothwall, etc.